# How to build a simple shell to run Javascript as a local mobile app?

Tags: javascript, mobile

Ideally I'd like to build the simplest possible shell so I can run my native Javascript as a mobile app. No idea how to do this without using something like Unity, which is terribly inefficient in this case.

*For reference, I coded the game on the iPad using pure JS with no libraries, as I only have wifi and couldn't depend on connectivity.  The app I used to code it, Textastic, allows me to run the code locally, I suspect by emulating a browser.  Essentially, if I could strip out all of Textastic's functions except for the one that lets me run the code locally, I'd have my shell. But I'm a noob so how to do this in the most efficient way (i.e. not using a framework with all kinds of things I don't need) is a little out of my wheelhouse.*

I want the game code to be open source as there will be kids who will likely want to hack it, thus the choice of Javascript. The core game code is <32KB but **efficiency is paramount** as most of the additional code will be for a weak AI involving massive recursion. (The total game tree is probably ~10^120, which can be profoundly pruned, but nevertheless...)

Comment: Looked into PhoneGap and family?

Comment: I have not but I will now!  (Thanks for the input @jdphenix, it is much appreciated.)